# mappageroute for mydomain/product to mydomain/products/product

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

At the moment Im getting a 404 error for any product page of the form
mydomain/product

I would like to map these to mydomain/showproduct.aspx?pagename=product

Is it something like
 routes.MapPageRoute(
           "Product",
           "{Prodname}",
           "~/showproduct.aspx"
           );
Not sure if this will work and not sure about the querystring

Answer (score 2):

That URL you would like to map looks more like a classic ASP.NET URL then an MVC URL. In MVC you are not linking to physical files but action methods in a controller class.

In MVC it should look more like: mydomain/products/show/productname

The default URL route should handle the above URL structure:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

EDIT:

If you have to do it the other way try something like this:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
   "Page",
   "{name}.aspx",
   new { controller = "Page", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```