# Routing issue: ASP.NET 4 or 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, webforms

I have encountered a problem with routing. I need to create this kind of route:

**http://www.site.com/index.html?parameter**

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.Ignore("{resource}.css/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.Ignore("{folder}/{*pathInfo}", new { folder = "Styles" });
        routes.Ignore("{resource}.js/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "Default",
            "{page}.html",
            "~/default.aspx"
        );
    }
}
```

I have successfully created this route:
**http://www.site.com/index.html/?parameter**

How do I remove the '/'(slash) from the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the slash from after html so it becomes the following:

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
      "Default",
      "{page}.html{*id}",
      "~/default.aspx"
);
```

Hopefully this helps

Comment: A path segment that contains more than one section, such as a literal section or a parameter, cannot contain a catch-all parameter.

Comment: Hmm ok change it back. How many routes do you have? Is that the first one in the list?

Comment: public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.Ignore("{resource}.css/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.Ignore("{folder}/{*pathInfo}", new { folder = "Styles" });
            routes.Ignore("{resource}.js/{*pathInfo}");

         
            routes.MapPageRoute(
                "Default",
                "{page}.html",
                "~/default.aspx"
            );
        }
    }

Comment: Is the answer on this page any good? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302071/mappageroute-for-mydomain-product-to-mydomain-products-product

Comment: No sorry i have seen this one

Comment: I am confused as well then. I have been looking at a lot of pages, and none have examples of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes i know, thanks for the urge to help, i would like to achieve is to ignore special character '?', that would fix it

Answer (score 0):

Define the route as:

```
  routes.MapPageRoute(
          "Default",
          "{page}.html",
          "~/default.aspx"
    );
```

And add the QueryString parameters in the code. QueryStrings will be handled normally.

Comment: No it's ignores my route and gives HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found